# Chrome not showing setting page when using --user-data-dir to open it

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome was updated automatically to version 78 from v77 a couple of days ago (Windows 10).

Everything worked fine on v77.

On v78, if I open Chrome via parameters `--user-data-dir` from a specific profile path, Chrome's setting page would not show properly. (Nothing is shown on page `chrome://settings/`)

I just tried `chrome://extensions/` and did not work either.